# How to customise UL > LI in flutter where using flutter_html plugin

Tags: html, list, flutter, widget, html-lists

I have a request to customise the `second line` of the text which is on `ul > li`. what issue I have is that the `bullet point is above the text`. how to fix this which is shown in the attachment below or any native way in flutter, I can get a proper bullet points? currently, as I told, I am using the `flutter_html` plugin and the listing is stored by `WYSIWYG editor` in DB. In short, it's an `HTML code`.

widget link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

[image]

```
Html(
  data: data.disclaimer,
  customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
  if (node is dom.Element) {
  switch (node.localName) {
  case "ul":
   return baseStyle.merge(Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 16));
    }
   }
  return baseStyle;
 },
),
```

Comment: use `RichText` / `Text.rich`

Comment: @pskink please see the code above and can you help me to modify this code ?

Comment: you are using some 3rd party libs that i have no knowledge of - instead i se: use standard flutter widgets

Comment: an example will be great as I am a newbie with flutter.

Comment: you have the examples in the official documentation for those two classes

Comment: I supposed you didn't get what I was talking about. I did have a look at the `RichText` from `flutter` but how to implement the bullet thing with it. should I get the paragraph and then break it into array, loop and use `text span`. or any easy way to implement. and example of that would be great.

Comment: check `InlineSpan` official documentation (but honestly you can use some std Unicode glyphs to represent the bullet you want)

Comment: but the basic stuff is like: `child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
  children: [
    TextSpan(text: '•', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
    TextSpan(text: ' Occaecat sint aute commodo consectetur do veniam fugiat quis exercitation culpa.'),
  ],
)),`

Comment: Currently working with some other solutions I have found. will update the results soon.

Comment: @princeoo7 what was your solution? you never updated the results here. I have a similar issue so would be helpful if you can share your solution as an answer

Comment: @andthereitgoes nothing was changed and the same code was used as we where short of time for that work. so no solution was posted here.

Comment: @princeoo7 thanks for your response - so are you still having issue with the bullet point is above the text?

Comment: @andthereitgoes never tried that scenario after that case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here is to use the bullet character '•' in a Text Widget. To have the text only aligned under the text, you can place the Widgets in a Row. With this, the text won't overlap on the bullet.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text('•'),
    Text(yourString),
  ],
)
```

Comment: not giving desired output.

Comment: this was the first approach I tried at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the follow widget to handle this.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UlWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? text;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final List<LiWidget> children;
  final EdgeInsets? contentPadding;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final double verticalSpacing;

  const UlWidget({
    this.text,
    this.textStyle,
    this.padding,
    this.contentPadding,
    this.verticalSpacing = 8.0,
    required this.children,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: padding ?? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (text != null)
            Text(
              text!,
              style: textStyle ??
                  TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
            ),
          if (text != null)
            const SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
          Padding(
            padding: contentPadding ??
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 12.0,
                  vertical: 8,
                ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: children
                  .expand((element) => [
                        element,
                        SizedBox(
                          height: verticalSpacing,
                        ),
                      ])
                  .toList(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LiWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final double dotSize;
  final Color? dotColor;

  const LiWidget({
    required this.data,
    this.style,
    this.dotColor,
    this.dotSize = 8,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.circle,
          size: dotSize,
          color: dotColor ?? Colors.grey.shade900,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 12,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            data,
            style: style,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
        UlWidget(
          text: 'This is a UL tag with the follow things:',
          children: [
            LiWidget(data: 'Somehting goes here;'),
            LiWidget(data: 'Another text goes here;'),
            LiWidget(data: 'And so on.'),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]